# Sorting/Grouping Items In A list

Tags: c#, list, group-by

I have a list of filenames that will look something like this:

```
SAN003A-S6cp-201607221655.SSHOW_SYS.tgz

SAN003A-S7cp-201607221655.SSHOW_SYS.tgz

BrocadeRK4-S4cp-201604140110.SSHOW_SYS.tgz

BrocadeRK4-S5cp-201604140110.SSHOW_SYS.tgz
```

The commonalities will be the 'SNcp' pattern, where N is a number. what's before and after that may differ.  It is machine generated output from a network switch.  I can have 1, 2 or more in the list.  I can handle 1 or 2.  Either means they are from the same switch. Files from the same switch will match before and after the 'SNcp'.   If there are more than 2 then it means logs from multiple switches are mixed in the same folder.  The above example there are 2 switches.   I need to be able to sort/and/or group by what comes before the 'SNcp' pattern.  I think I need a regex to do it, but when I search for grouping lists by regex I get how to do named groups.  So I'm not sure what the predicate should be for a GroupBy.  The starting position of the 'SNcp' pattern will also vary, so I'm not sure how I would do a Substring.

Comment: How many groups would you like to get for the items above? I mean, `N` is different in all four, so are you looking for four groups in the above example?

Comment: Instead of regular expressions you might want to get the index of that first dash with `string.IndexOf` and then use it to get the desired substrings you want to group on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - For the above, I want two groups, one with the filenames that start with 'SAN003A' and one with the filenames that start with 'BrocadeRK4'

Comment: @DavidGreen why not `list.GroupBy(str => str.Split('-')[0])` then?

Comment: thats a good idea.  I think I am going to use the dictionary approach though.  a bit more readable and I need a bit of persistence on the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to do this reliably, you'll need to manipulate the fact that you do, in fact, know that there's a pattern and reason to the various things.  I'll assume the sort here is A-Z descending.  Have some general algorithm:

```
Create a Dictionary<String, List<File>>.
FOREACH File
   collect the first substring (0 to the first -)
   try to add the file to the dictionary using the substring as a key
      if it works, go to the next one
   Catch if the Key doesn't exist
      add the substring to the dictionary as a key with a new list
      add the file to the dictionary using the new key.
end FOREACH
FOREACH key in the dictionary
  sort the list alphabetically
end FOREACH
```

So, dictionaries are really good at grouping things by a commonality, which you've made apparent is either the Switch key (SNc) or the name to the left of it (SAN3000A and the like).  We can do this because also there is a common delimiter (-) for all the potential files, so I can reliably 'guess' where my key is coming from.

Comment: that's an interesting thought. he value could be a list with the 2 files from each switch in the list....

Comment: Right.  Though, honestly there's a reason I answered with a general algorithm.  You could change the condition in the collection step with any condition you want to group them up.  This solution also lets you get granular by going Dictionary<String, Dictionary<string, list>> and repeating the same process for the first part (outer key) and second part (inner key).  Dictionaries are great for this!  I'm a fan too of Dictionary <String, Function> to get some real mileage out of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, what you want to do, It can be useful for you:

```
var files = new[]
{
    "SAN003A-S6cp-201607221655.SSHOW_SYS.tgz",
    "SAN003A-S7cp-201607221655.SSHOW_SYS.tgz",
    "BrocadeRK4-S4cp-201604140110.SSHOW_SYS.tgz",
    "BrocadeRK4-S5cp-201604140110.SSHOW_SYS.tgz"
};

var regex = new Regex("-(S[0-9]+cp)-", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var grouped = files.GroupBy(x => regex.Match(x).Groups[1].Value);
if (grouped.Any(x => x.Count() > 2))
{
    //  logs from multiple switches are mixed in the same folder
}
```